# Use the result set of a class method into another class method

Tags: java, variables, methods

i have a class A in which there is a method Method1, in Method1 i want to pass the "rs" to class B method. how can i do it? try different things but unsuccessful.

Note: I did not write the full method code just gave an scenario to find the solution from you.

```
public class A {

    Resultset rs = null;

    public void method1() {

        this.rs = this.stmt.executeQuery(this.query);

        // while (this.rs.next()) {
        // int id = rs.getInt("node_Id");
        // String name = rs.getString("node_Name");
        // String par = rs.getString("node_Parent");
        // int lvl = rs.getInt("node_Level");
        // System.out.println(+id+" "+name+" "+par+" "+lvl);}

        if (success == 0) {
            this.conn.rollback();
        } else {
            System.out.println("rs" + rs);
            this.conn.commit();
        }

    }
```

now i want to use the variables id,name,par,lvl in another class method like
 following

```
public class B{

    public void usage(){    
         //in here i want to get the varibles id,name,par,lvl 
    }
}
```

Comment: `I did not write the full method code just gave an scenario to find the solution from you.` Just FYI we are not here to give the solution.

Comment: Note that a `ResultSet` lifecycle depends on the `Statement` and the `Connection` so if you want to keep the `ResultSet` instance for later use, you need to keep the `Statement` and `Connection` where the `ResultSet` "came" from open. Once you close the `Statement`, the `ResultSet` won't be usable anymore.

Comment: Use CachedRowSet.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you made these variables to be **local** variables within `method1()` (which is by the way a really bad name for a method - always use names that **mean** something, even in examples).

Because of that, you can only *pass* them around, by well, passing then, such as

```
B someB instance = ... // however that gets created
while (this.rs.next()) {
  int id = rs.getInt("node_Id");
  someB.doSomethingWith(id);
```

That's it. But the **better** approach would be to have, say a class `C` that *wraps* around all the information you want to pass around.

Then instead of creating and passing the individual values, you would collect the required values, and use those to create an instance of your new C class. And then you pass *that* object to whatever method that is going to need it.